# How to use attributes in an Inspec command?

Tags: shell, chef-infra, inspec

I defined some basic Inspec tests to check if a loadbalancer is active:

```
proxy = attribute('proxy_netlb_arn')

control 'Checks if all the ECE Load balancers are active ' do
impact 1.0
title 'Checks if all the ECE Load balancers are active'
describe command("aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers --load-balancer-arn proxy['value'] | jq -r '.[][].State.Code'") do
    its('stdout') { should match "active" }
end
end
```

I use a variable called "proxy" which contains the ARN of the Loadbalancer. Unfortunately the variable is not recognized as such because it is inside the command.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't have an attributes.yml file defining the variable name? Means that you can just pass the file instead of the static name.

Comment: yes i pass the attribute file when i execute the profile using the "attrs"-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use [string interpolation](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/syntax/literals_rdoc.html) to get the value of your string variable.

assuming `proxy['value']` returns the value of the `proxy` variable. then you can do it as follows:

```
proxy = attribute('proxy_netlb_arn')

control 'Checks if all the ECE Load balancers are active ' do
impact 1.0
title 'Checks if all the ECE Load balancers are active'
describe command("aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers --load-balancer-arn #{proxy['value']} | jq -r '.[][].State.Code'") do
    its('stdout') { should match "active" }
end
end
```